# Отслеживание загрузки скрипта

Tags: javascript

Привет.
Как можно решить задачу:

1. -в случае удачной загрузки скрипта вызвать подключение другого файла( и
           его выполнение) а затем выполнить
           исходный файл.
2. -если неудачное подключение- вызвать подключение  файла error.js.

Понимаю что прошу очень много.Нашел вот http://javascript.ru/blog/Ilya-Kantor/Zagruzka-dannyh-cherez-SCRIPT-s-otlovom-oshibok ,но он у меня некорректно работает. 
Интересует пока вариант на чистом JS.

Comment: Попробуйте получше продумать архитектуру.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте загрузить скрипт с `dataType=='text'`, в случае успеха запустить его можно через `eval()`, хотя это и не есть красиво.

Если скрипт чужой, то при загрузке через jsonp он попытается выполниться в первую очередь. Можно попробовать перед началом его загрузки выполнять "свой" правильный скрипт и прятать его результат, а в случае ошибки загрузки требуемого скрипта делать откат (или просто не показывать результат действий своего) и выполнять скрипт для ошибки.